# How to merge multiple generators?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I read `InputStream` using generator:

```
public static Flowable<byte[]> from(final InputStream is) {
    return Flowable.generate(new Consumer<Emitter<byte[]>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Emitter<byte[]> emitter) throws Exception {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count = is.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1) {
                emitter.onComplete();
            } else if (count < bufferSize) {
                emitter.onNext(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, count));
            } else {
                emitter.onNext(buffer);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It's ok. But I have two streams from process:

```
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
```

I want read them using one thread. I think it's not possible because reading - blocking operation.

But **main** task - I want merge these streams into one:

```
//IllegalStateException: onNext already called in this generate turn
Flowable<byte[]> stdOutAndStdErr = from(stderr).mergeWith(from(stdout)
```

Is that possible with "generators"?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a few years late to help you, but for anyone else falling into this trap, I give you [this great article](https://android.jlelse.eu/i-created-a-flowable-and-i-liked-it-7ab2af54f94a).

In short, you cannot use `Flowable.generate()` with an uncontrolled source. You have to use `Flowable.create()`. An uncontrolled source is a source where you are not in control of when the next data comes along. A controlled source is something like an iterator where next value is in control of the consumer.